# Linphone installation: questions about remote gnome

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I am going through the steps of installing Linphone, following this.
https://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone/downloads

When I typed the command
flatpak --user install --from https://linphone.org/flatpak/linphone.flatpakref

Terminal said
The application com.belledonnecommunications.linphone depends on runtimes from https://sdk.gnome.org/repo/
configure this as a new remote 'gnome'? (y/n)

I wasn't sure but I said yes to that.

Then Terminal said:
Required runtime for com.belledonnecommunications.linphone/x86_64/4.4.1 (runtime /org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/1.6) found in remote gnome.
Do you want to install it? (y/n)

Just wasn't sure what this all means and the implications.

Comment: The remotes are dependencies that flatpak requires in order to install the package.